# Exclude certain days/time from query results? (Ex. Thursday's midnight-2am EST)

Tags: datetime, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am newer to KQL and I am trying to write a query against configuration changes made to files with an extension of ".config" and would like to remove results that are generated under the "TimeGenerated [UTC]" column. The results should **exclude Thursday's from midnight- 2am EST.** Understanding that TimeGenerated is in UTC, the query should be offsetting that to return EST.
Would someone be able to assist me in writing this? Not sure how to write it up as to have it return the results that exclude the specific time frame. Below is what I have so far:

```
ConfigurationChange
| where dayofweek(datetime_add('hour', -5, TimeGenerated)) != 4d and hourofday(datetime_add('hour', -5, TimeGenerated)) !in(0, 1) // <---
| where ConfigChangeType in ("Files")
| where FileSystemPath endswith ".config"
| sort by TimeGenerated
| render table
```

Comment: Hi @Dan, did the answer below help? If yes, please accept it (see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top) to learn how and why). If the answer isn't clear or doesn't answer your question, please add a comment elaborating what else is needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `4d` with `4`, because `dayofweek()` returns the number of day (between 0 and 6).